# Can anyone explain the dry run, output behind this function below for j=2?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int p(int);
void main()
{
    int j;
    scanf("%d",&j);
    p(j);
    printf("Return value: %d",j);
}
int p(int j)
{
    int i;
    for( i=j; i>0; p(i-1) )
    {
        printf("%d",i); 
    }
    return(j);
}
```

Please explain the dry run and output as well. I have trouble finding the logic behind this function.

Comment: Surprise: Last print in `main()` will produce `2`. Ask how?

Comment: Maybe you could specify what you get (the 'dry run') and what you expect and then ask a specific question?
It appears to contain an infinite loop and infinite recursion..

Comment: @SouravGhosh, what last print? It will never come to that :)

Comment: @JensGustedt Hah, you're very true sir. :) Please append _if_ to my earlier comment, then. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: "Surprise: Last print in main() will produce 2. Ask how? **if**"? ;-)

Comment: @Kenney - I don't see any infinite recursion here, just infinite looping.

Comment: @owacoder Right, recursion is bound by `j`; after that, it looks like it might print "1", for a while.

Comment: I want to know how come I am getting an infinite loop? In dry run on paper I get 21 as output.   Can anyone explain me the control flow and cause of recursion

Answer (score 0):

The function `p()` will never return on positive input. In the loop, `i` is not modified, therefore the condition `i > 0` always holds true for a positive input. With a negative or zero input, a single line will be printed: "Return value: x" where x is your input value.

Without knowing what output you are expecting, we really can't help you improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

may be this will give an error because the function p() return int value so you need to store return value in any int variable.